# Passing numpy array vs scalar to function gives inconsistent results

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple program to calculate a function.

```
import numpy as np

def fn(n, x0):
    return (np.sin(np.arcsin(x0**0.5)*2**n))**2

n = np.arange(100)

x0 = 0.3
print(fn(n, x0))
print(fn(50, x0))
```

The result generated:

```
[0.3        0.84       0.5376     0.99434496 0.02249224 0.08794536
 0.32084391 0.87161238 0.44761695 0.98902407 0.04342185 0.16614558
 0.55416492 0.98826465 0.04639054 0.17695382 0.58256466 0.97273231
 0.10609667 0.37936067 0.94178461 0.21930545 0.68484228 0.86333333
 0.47195556 0.99685404 0.01254426 0.04954761 0.18837059 0.61154843
 0.95022779 0.18917976 0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
0.9931071163166798
```

The two results are inconsistent because the element of index 50 (where n=50) in the results of `fn(n, x0)` is zero, whereas evaluating the function for `50` results in a non-zero value. Why is this the case?

Why are most elements of the resulting array for `f(n, x0)` zeros? This shouldn't be the case according to the math.

Comment: Because `np.arange(100)` is not the same as `50`?

Comment: What I actually wanted to know is that why the resulting numpy array shows discrepancy from the result of the math. Most of the elements are zeros which shouldn't be the case. I used n=50 to check just to make sure they really shouldn't be zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For evaluation of math expressions where decimal values are expected in the results, it is important to specifically define the numeric values in the function as floats:

```
def fn(n, x0):      
  return (np.sin(np.arcsin(x0**0.5)*2.**n))**2.
```

Then, for `(fn(n, x0))` I get the result:

```
[0.3        0.84       0.5376     0.99434496 0.02249224 0.08794536
 0.32084391 0.87161238 0.44761695 0.98902407 0.04342185 0.16614558
 0.55416492 0.98826465 0.04639054 0.17695382 0.58256466 0.97273231
 0.10609667 0.37936067 0.94178461 0.21930545 0.68484228 0.86333333
 0.47195556 0.99685404 0.01254426 0.04954761 0.18837059 0.61154843
 0.95022779 0.18917976 0.61356311 0.94841368 0.19570069 0.62960771
 0.93280737 0.25071114 0.75142025 0.74715144 0.75566467 0.7385423
 0.77239028 0.70321414 0.83481605 0.55159286 0.98935271 0.04213571
 0.16144118 0.5415117  0.99310712 0.02738149 0.10652697 0.38071589
 0.9430852  0.21470202 0.67442025 0.87831031 0.42752525 0.97898964
 0.08227569 0.3020256  0.84322454 0.52878765 0.99668508 0.01321571
 0.05216421 0.19777242 0.63463397 0.92749478 0.26899286 0.78654281
 0.67157288 0.88225099 0.41553673 0.97146383 0.11088744 0.39436567
 0.95536555 0.17056885 0.56590047 0.98262851 0.06827888 0.25446749
 0.75885515 0.73197605 0.78474845 0.67567327 0.8765556  0.43282351
 0.98194928 0.07089957 0.26349128 0.7762545  0.69473381 0.84831498
 0.51470671 0.99913485 0.0034576  0.01378259]
```

And `(fn(n, x0))[50]` evaluates to `0.993107116317`.

Although I get these results with `n = np.arange(100)`, it is good practice to keep everything as floats and also use `n = np.arange(100.)`.

Comment: Still none of the element should be zero. I use n=90 to check and the result is still not zero.

Comment: This function is an analytical solution of the map x_n = 4x(1-x) which is a chaotic map, so none of the element of `f(n, x0)` should be zero ...

Comment: And it's even more perplexing when we have yielded different results, however the later elements are all zeros which should not be the case

Comment: Oh I think I've discovered why. Related to floats / ints. Still not sure why the initial results were different between us. Modifying my answer...

Comment: Oh problem solved, thanks! I have encountered problems before because I didn't specify the number with floats already, I should really keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

Please be warned that simply replacing ints with floats is not a proper solution here. In fact the values returned by this method for larger `n` are completely bogus.

Let me demonstrate this using `bigfloat` a library providing arbitrary precision floats.

Using float64, the value returned for n = 99, x0 = 0.3

```
>>> fn(99., 0.3)
0.013782590413701074
```

is ~0.0138.

Now, we'll compute the correct value using a ridiculously high precision of 1000 bits.

```
>>> def fnbig(n, x0):
...     n, x0 = map(bigfloat.BigFloat, (n, x0))
...     return bigfloat.pow(bigfloat.sin(bigfloat.asin(bigfloat.sqrt(x0))*bigfloat.pow(2, n)), 2)
... 
>>> 
>>> bigfloat.setcontext(bigfloat.Context(1000))
```

Note that 0.3 has to be entered as a string because the float64 generated from the literal 0.3 already carries an error that is too large to get a correct answer.

```
>>> fnbig('99', '0.3')
BigFloat.exact('0.363780859940401348053691101648398065131477584225708461696799538248050278540782181716110363889498612214432889606382752875154011855764448898240841915231368492158238806206980341185053867226372528105024157964509865633147960964164133657255856469376571664623973084231004713906743471127849494395877727320492003', precision=1000)
```

This returns ~0.364.

To make sure this is correct let us double the precision to 2000 bits.

```
>>> bigfloat.setcontext(bigfloat.Context(2000))
>>> 
>>> fnbig('99', '0.3')
BigFloat.exact('0.3637808599404013480536911016483980651314775842257084616967995382480502785407821817161103638894986122144328896063827528751540118557644488982408419152313684921582388062069803411850538672263725281050241579645098656331479609641641336572558564693765716646239730842310047139067975945820088206827783571320258628882284629795545097600685961974610320482001970915733612836861863674071009032317962504679512051859460424746278292327826581975723619660002116915303723311156451829258099225827808017028059470793304713100650332080089174169114171398280313842625628566029927379227478504732491009738418661061753082431884081337', precision=2000)
```

The values returned at precisions 1000 and 2000 are essentially the same, so we can be confident they are correct.

The value returned using "normal" float arithmetic in contrast is pretty much a random number.

Comment: Excellent observation. This article (Sarra & Meador, 2011) looks like a good reference related to this issue: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/476b/3dd90ab547adb38d451a8d9f342756d9975c.pdf

Comment: And equation 2 in this article is the same equation we are dealing with: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5915552_Double_precision_errors_in_the_logistic_map_Statistical_study_and_dynamical_interpretation

Answer (score -1):

This requires some debugging that's pretty typical for working with `numpy`.  A couple of the common causes are

1. Integer datatypes suffering from overflows or integer division
2. Floating point datatypes giving inexact behavior
3. Calculations causing `nan` or `inf`  propagate to subsequent steps

The way to figure out which cause (or if it's an entirely different cause) is to go through step by step.

```
>>> x0 = 0.3
>>> x0**0.5
0.5477225575051661
```

No problem here.  Not surprising, since this step is unrelated to `n`.  The next step

```
 >>> 2**n
array([                   1,                    2,                    4,
                          8,                   16,                   32,
                         64,                  128,                  256,
                        512,                 1024,                 2048,
                       4096,                 8192,                16384,
                      32768,                65536,               131072,
                     262144,               524288,              1048576,
                    2097152,              4194304,              8388608,
                   16777216,             33554432,             67108864,
                  134217728,            268435456,            536870912,
                 1073741824,           2147483648,           4294967296,
                 8589934592,          17179869184,          34359738368,
                68719476736,         137438953472,         274877906944,
               549755813888,        1099511627776,        2199023255552,
              4398046511104,        8796093022208,       17592186044416,
             35184372088832,       70368744177664,      140737488355328,
            281474976710656,      562949953421312,     1125899906842624,
           2251799813685248,     4503599627370496,     9007199254740992,
          18014398509481984,    36028797018963968,    72057594037927936,
         144115188075855872,   288230376151711744,   576460752303423488,
        1152921504606846976,  2305843009213693952,  4611686018427387904,
       -9223372036854775808,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0])
```

Clearly shows the problematic behavior.  There's a bunch of zeros, preceded by a large negative number.  Looking more closely at the result

```
>>> (2**n).dtype
dtype('int64')
```

you can see that 2 to the `n`th power is still an integer.  It appears a simple bit shift is taking place, resulting in all zeros when the result can no longer be contained in an integer datatype.

The fix is simple, use `n.astype(float)` instead of `n`.